# CSS syntax: ".one.column" ".two.column", am I reading this right?

Tags: html, css, syntax, css-selectors

I just found out about the Skeleton boilerplate, which uses grids. This is the css on github: https://github.com/dhgamache/Skeleton/blob/master/stylesheets/skeleton.css

The different column classes are layed out `.one.columns`, `.two.columns`, etc.

I've not seen this syntax in CSS before.

Am I right to assume that `.one.columns {}` is different from `.one, .columns {}` in that the former affects only elements with `class="one columns"` while the latter affects both elements with `class="one"` and `class="columns"`?

That is:

```
.one.columns = .one AND .columns
.one, .columns =  .one OR .columns
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.class1.class2 {}` refers to all elements with **both** classes `class1` and `class2`.

`.class1 .class2 {}` refers to all elements with class `class2` which are descendants of an element with class `class1`.

`.class1, .class2 {}` refers to all elements with both/either class `class1` and/or class `class2`.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

Chaining them together without whitespace matches all with those classes present.

A comma between them means to select any element which matches a comma delimited selector.

Answer (score 2):

When CSS selectors are concatenated, they all must apply to an element to be selected.  Just as `div.foo` means elements that are divs and also have class `foo`, `.one.columns` means elements that have class `one` and also have class `columns`.

When CSS selectors are separated by commas, it means the styles apply to any elements that match the first selector, and also any elements that match the second selector.  Just as `h1, h2` means, these styles are for `h1` elements and also `h2` elements, `.one, .columns` means the styles apply to all elements with a class of `one`, and also all elements with a class of `columns`.